# How to send Math functions to Sql Server using Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to send a math function to sql server using entity framework 6.

I have a simple query:

```cs
using(var db = databaseContext)
{
    var query = db.Foo.Select(x => Math.Sin(x.bar));
}
```

However this gives me an exception.

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'Double Sin(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into
>   a store expression.

The problem is that entity framework doesn't know how to translate Math.sin into a Sql Server equivalent. Are there any other classes that I can use that will work?

Comment: Use `Math.Sin` on the code side

Comment: I can't do this in the code side. The example above is a toy example but in realize I'm doing this on a very large database with millions of rows. On top of this I need to be able to sort by this math function and page my results. Doing this on the code side is not an option.

Comment: @Soto please mark the correct answere as "correct", since another answere has more upvotes - other users with the same problem can see the right answere then first. As you can see, the answere with code-based solution still gets upvotes, which costs performance! So would you please?!

Answer (score 4):

i would first load the data from the db and do such calculations in memory

```
using(var db = databaseContext)
{
    var listofFoo= db.Foo.toList();
    var listofFooSin = listofFoo.Select(x => Math.Sin(x.bar));
}
```

Comment: This approach will loop results twice.

Comment: It won't? Or does `ToList()` loop through all the items? check EF-Code what `ToList` really does. It's opensource :)

Comment: I can't do this in the code side. The example above is a toy example but in realize I'm doing this on a very large database with millions of rows. On top of this I need to be able to sort by this math function and page my results. Doing this on the code side is not an option.

Comment: Only option then to do put this bussiness logic to DB. Create a store procedure which calculates it

Comment: @Soto - everything you want to do on database side can be done in code side. In code side you get your code in more readable way and in some cases even faster then in database

Comment: @Fabio: sorting and paging by first retrieving all the rows and then processing on the client side inherently doesn't scale. That's a typical example of processing that you want to do on the database. Nobody cares for readability if they have to wait 30 seconds. Your theory is sound, it just doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 4):

A ton of MSSQL-specific functions are exposed as static methods in the class `System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions` - but not all.
For `Sin`you can use `SqlFunctions.Sin` and don't need to use linq to object. the default `Sin` is not a supported function in EF

Comment: I'm not sure if you intended this or your answer is just confusingly worded, but [`SqlFunctions.Sin`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd466178) certainly exists. There's no need to use LINQ to Objects.

Comment: Yeah I agree. You gave the correct function 'SqlFunctions' but then you say sin is not supported... but it is.

Comment: haha was wrong worded.. yeah, was really confused :D I edited my post :)

Comment: @Soto and please mark the answere as "correct", since another answere has more upvotes than mine - other users with the same problem can see the right answere then first.

Answer (score 1):

Your object is not REALIZED yet and as such cannot do complex functions on it.  This is similar with using extension methods and other things.  The magic of just adding a 'ToList()' in many things with EntityFramework will make it realized and as such able to do more things.  When in doubt with Entity use a 'ToList()'.  The problem is that the objects are not fulling realized when you do something similar to:

```
'context.(object).Select(x => (docomplexThing(x))'
```

Entity has some base properties and operations like equalitative operations and lambda functions it can do.  It cannot do heavy duty methods until the object is cast to a more realized object in memory or projected to something first.  ToList accomplishes this.  It is not just Math operations but encryption and custom made extension methods. Sometimes they will work in cases but most of the time not.  I always think of it like the ADO.NET layers where you have a disconnected and a connected layer.  The context and grabbing things from it is connected and as such does not expose a lot of options, once it is disconnected through or projected, you have free reign to go nuts on things.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  using (var context = new TesterEntities())
  {
    var items = context.tePersons.ToList().Select(x => Math.Sin(x.PersonId));        
  }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```